# What does "on a hiding to nothing" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, british-english

I watched a movie with English actors just the other day and came across this phrase in the dialogue.   What does it mean, and who would typically use it?

**EDIT**: 
 What is the sense of the *hide* in *hiding*? How does it contribute to the meaning of the idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, it refers to a situation in which it's pointless to try because it's impossible to win: either you're going to *get a hiding*, that is, take a (metaphorical) beating on your *hide*, or else...*nothing*. There is nothing else. You're going to lose, and you're probably going to lose so badly that your opponent is going to gain *nothing* from beating you.

Comment: I liked you answer because the phrase doesn't just mean you aren't likely to win, the major emphasis is actually being beaten in trying to do so and high risk of attempting it.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is *on a hiding to nothing*, it means they [don't stand to gain anything](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-a-hiding-to-nothing.html) from their endeavour: in a sporting context, it can be used to mean that they are bound to lose, or that they are so sure to win that the will gain nothing from it (for instance because the bookmakers' odds will be so poor - or simply because there is no prestige to be gained from beating a far inferior team). But its use is not restricted to sport: it can be used in any other context where the prospects are similar.

There is no strong association with any particular class or region, so far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 5):

And more specifically for the second part of OP's question:

> but in what sense is the *hide* in *hiding* contributing the meaning of the idiom?

Here, "hiding" is a noun used as [a colloquial near synonym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hiding#hiding__3) for "a beating". According to the *OED*, it goes back to activities involved in [tanning a hide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanning), related to the verb *hide*<sup>2</sup>, "2. To beat the hide or skin of; to flog, thrash". For the noun, *OED* gives this example from 1822 (not the oldest) for the equation with "a thrashing":

> Giving him a severe beating, or, what was called, a ‘hideing’.
>   Thomas Bewick, *Select fables...*, 118.

Its use in the phrase *[a hiding to nothing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hiding#hiding__7)* means to get no benefit from this painful activity, as described already in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

To be faced with a situation which is pointless, as a successful outcome is impossible.

[More information here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-a-hiding-to-nothing.html)